# Listing all the common value of second column followed by unique name in first value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to visualize this specific condition. Consider a patient visits hospital for regular checkup. First he visits to the internal medicine,next to  ENT, ORTHOPEDIAC and pharmacy another time when he visits the hospital he visits internal medicine and laboratory and ENT and pharmacy.
Every patient visit certain departments while visiting the hospitals.

---

```
PatientName Department
Alice       INTERNAL
Alice       ENT
Alice       ORTHO
Alice       PHARMACY
Bob         Internal
Bob         ORTHO
Bob         PHARMACY
```

Now How am I get the departments in a cvs according to the department travelled by unique users in this formatt like

```
INTERNAL, ENT, ORTHO, PHARMACY
INTERNAL, ORTHO, PHARMACY
SKIN, EYE, OPERATION, PHARMACY
INTERNAL, , , 
...
...
MEDICAL, NEURO, PSYCH, PHARMACY
...
...
```

What set of rules i.e. sql queries will provide this output in tabular form? I can convert it into csv once it is downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group_concat` to retrieve a comma separated list of departments for each user.

```
select PatientName, group_concat(Department)
from mytable
group by PatientName
```

If you want the departments to appear in a certain order then user an `order by` inside `group_concat`

```
 group_concat(department order by department)
```